# Find the maximum value in decision tree

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, decision-tree, party

I created decision tree with Party package in R.
I'm trying to get the route/branch with the maximum value.

It can be mean value that came from box-plot [image: Picture 1]

and it can be probability value that came from binary tree [image: Picture 2]
<sub>(source: [rdatamining.com](http://www.rdatamining.com/_/rsrc/1421496897574/examples/decision-tree/iris_ctree_simple.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Max value in the first tree will be in node 8.
Max value in the second tree will be in  node 5[2].
How we will recognize it automatically?

Comment: iterate over the leaves and select what you are interested in?

Comment: Yes.
I want to know which decisions i need to do if i want the max mean (pic 1)

Comment: You need to go over the recursive structure of the output object from party. Probably the easier is that you take [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621611/converting-ctree-output-into-json-format-for-d3-tree-layout) as a starting point, and from the output format there you select the info you want. If you have more doubts, just post them in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done pretty easily actually, though while your definition of *maximum value* is clear for a *regression tree*, it is not very clear for a *classification tree*, as in each node different level can have it's own maximum

Either way, here's a pretty simple helper function that will return you the predictions for each type of tree

```
GetPredicts <- function(ct){
      f <- function(ct, i) nodes(ct, i)[[1]]$prediction
      Terminals <- unique(where(ct))
      Predictions <- sapply(Terminals, f, ct = ct)
      if(is.matrix(Predictions)){
        colnames(Predictions) <- Terminals
        return(Predictions)
       } else {
        return(setNames(Predictions, Terminals))
       }
}
```

Now luckily you've took your trees from the examples of `?ctree`, so we can test them (next time, please provide the code you used yourself)

---

**Regression Tree** (your frist tree)

```
## load the package and create the tree
library(party)
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
airct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq, 
               controls = ctree_control(maxsurrogate = 3))
plot(airct)
```

Now, test the function

```
res <- GetPredicts(airct)
res
#        5        3        6        9        8 
# 18.47917 55.60000 31.14286 48.71429 81.63333
```

So we've got the predictions per each terminal node. You can easily proceed with `which.max(res)` from here (I'll leave it for you to decide)

---

**Classification tree** (your second tree)

```
irisct <- ctree(Species ~ .,data = iris)
plot(irisct, type = "simple")
```

Run the function

```
res <- GetPredicts(irisct)
res
#      2          5   6          7
# [1,] 1 0.00000000 0.0 0.00000000
# [2,] 0 0.97826087 0.5 0.02173913
# [3,] 0 0.02173913 0.5 0.97826087
```

Now, the output is a bit harder to read because each class has it's own probabilities. You could make this a bit more readable using

```
row.names(res) <- levels(iris$Species)
res
#            2          5   6          7
# setosa     1 0.00000000 0.0 0.00000000
# versicolor 0 0.97826087 0.5 0.02173913
# virginica  0 0.02173913 0.5 0.97826087
```

The, you could do something like the following in order to get the overall maximum value

```
which(res == max(res), arr.ind = TRUE)
#        row col
# setosa   1   1
```

For column/row maxes, you could do

```
matrixStats::colMaxs(res)
# [1] 1.0000000 0.9782609 0.5000000 0.9782609
matrixStats::rowMaxs(res)
# [1] 1.0000000 0.9782609 0.9782609
```

But, again, I'll leave to you to decide on how to proceed from here.

Comment: Hello David,
this is exactly what i meant.

Comment: There is a way to pull out from the tree the route of the highest value? For example, in the regression tree I'll ask the route of node 8 (temp > 82, wind <10.3) Thanks!!!